# Linear Transformation Inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inverse

The linear transformation $T : \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ that reflects vectors about a line $\ell$ through the origin is invertible.

Thus, $T^{-1} = \space ?$ $\space\space\space$ *(Note: reflecting twice is the identity)*

I am new to the topic of linear transformation and was wondering how to get the inverse of a linear transformation when there is no specific function/equation given. When given the vectors, then I would calculate for the determinant as the first step, but with this question above, I'm not even sure what the first step is. Hoping someone could help me!

Comment: Hint: what action undoes a reflection?

Comment: Negative sign? @SeanRoberson

Comment: Not necessarily. Try this: Go in your image editor choice and reflect an image. Now do the same reflection. What do you notice?

Comment: $$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
\cos \theta & \sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & - \cos \theta \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Reflecting twice returns the image to its original position. Does this mean that a reflection undoes a reflection itself? @SeanRoberson